# How to change a value of an object in an array of nested objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through an array of objects and if a nested object has a certain value change this value to something else.

In this example of dummy data if fruit equals 'plum' change the value to 'strawberry'

I think I can achieve this through using map.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
const array = [
  {
    things: [
      { car: 'ford' },
      { colour: 'red' },
      {
        food: [
          { veg: 'beans' },
          { fruit: 'plum' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {},
  {},
]

const newArray = array.map((item) => {
  if (item.things.food.fruit === 'plum') return item.things.food.fruit = 'strawberry'
})
```

Comment: `things` is an array, so you need to indicate the index of the object to access, you can't just access `food` directly. The shape of your data lacks consistency (or normalization) and so the task is actually quite complex.

Answer (score 1):

reformat your data. it will be the best way moving forward.

```
  const array = [
    {
      car: 'ford',
      colour: 'red',
      food: {
          veg: 'beans',
          fruit: 'plum',
      },
    }
  ];
```

this way you can access the data like you want to `food.fruit` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a recursive function that loops over each item in an array. If it encounters an object it will change on of its values if needed or call the function itself again

```js
const array = [
  {
    things: [
      { car: 'ford' },
      { colour: 'red' },
      {
        food: [
          { veg: 'beans' },
          { fruit: 'plum' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {},
  {},
];

const changePlum = (arr, changeTo = 'strawberry') => (
    arr.map(a => {
      for (let k in a) {
          if (Array.isArray(a[k])) {
              a[k] = changePlum(a[k], changeTo);
          } else if(a[k] === 'plum') {
              a[k] = changeTo;
          }
      }
      return a;
    })
)

const res = changePlum(array);
console.log(res);
```